# Complicated Intersection With Maps

Tags: dictionary, set-theory

I have two maps of the same K, V types such that

Key is the Country

Value is a Map of

so the overall Map structure is

```
 Map <String, Map<String, List<City>>> m1, m2;
```

Now I want to find out what entries of the map are same and which ones are different

For example:

```
m1 =    { India = [TA -> {City1, City2, City3}   KA -> {City1, City2}]
          USA =   [WI -> {City1, City2, City3},  OH -> {City1, City2}] }

m2 =    { India = [TA -> {City1, City2, City3} ]
          USA =   [WI -> {City1, City3},         DC -> {City1}] }
```

The output should be

```
Common = { India = [TA -> {City1, City2, City3} ]
           USA = [WI -> {City1, City3}] }
```

Is there a better way to get this information than to loop through the entire list and check line by line (even if there is an already defined method that does this, it would be great)?

I will use this so that I know that over the past few years the only thing that has changed is the few cities and few states.

Would be glad to clarify further if required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the type of collection you are going to use to store your data. The other factor is a technology you are going to use. Then it also depends on how efficient versus how readable is your code. My favorite language is C# so I would go for it. Then implement the whole thing - similarly to your suggestion - as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<City>>>`.

To get the data I used LINQ as it gives you quite readable code.

I implemented your example as below (for the sake of simplicity the cities are simple strings):

```
var m1 = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>>
{
    {
        "India", new Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
                    {
                        {"TA", new List<string> {"City1", "City2", "City3"}},
                        {"KA", new List<string> {"City1", "City2"}}
                    }
    },
    {
        "USA", new Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
                    {
                        {"WI", new List<string> {"City1", "City2", "City3"}},
                        {"OH", new List<string> {"City1", "City2"}}
                    }
    }
};

var m2 = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>>
{
    {
        "India", new Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
                    {
                        {"TA", new List<string> {"City1", "City2", "City3"}},
                    }
    },
    {
        "USA", new Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
                    {
                        {"WI", new List<string> {"City1", "City3"}},
                        {"DC", new List<string> {"City1"}}
                    }
    }
};
```

And the operation to get your result is the `Intersect` method applied on each level of the nested collection:

```
var result = m1.Keys.Intersect(m2.Keys)
                    .ToDictionary(k => k, k => m1[k].Keys.Intersect(m2[k].Keys)
                        .ToDictionary(l => l, l => m1[k][l].Intersect(m2[k][l])));
```

If you debug that and expand `result` you will see it returns the values you expected in your example.

Note, that your `City` class has to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface so it can be correctly processed in the `Intersect` method. Sample implementation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Sound logic. Thank you for this. i will try it and get back if it is working :). Thanks again

Comment: As mentioned in the reply I tested it on simple strings. If you copy past the dictionaries and the query into visual studio project and run it you will get the results. But with `City` class you need the `IEquatable` interface implemented to test if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

For the two maps, the best method would be to increment through every key.

However, for the list if the lists are sorted, use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) through the elements of the list.

Cheers!

Comment: I see, thank you for the thoughts. aslo they are not sorted unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, probably heapsort then binary search.